# Write aac file to disc using node js

Tags: node.js

I am recording an internet radio stream using the node.js Icecast module.
The format of the stream is AAC.
I am trying to write it to disk as AAC:

```
const icecast = require('icecast');
const url = 'http://webradio.ffh.de';

let ice;

var fs = require('fs');
var aacfile = fs.createWriteStream('test.aac');

ice = icecast.get(url, res => {
    res.pipe(aacfile);
});


setTimeout(()=>{
    ice.end();
},5000);
```

The aac file test.aac is empty.
How can I solve this? Or how else can I write the AAC stream to disk?

Comment: It's an MP3 stream and this is the URL: https://mp3.ffh.de/radioffh/hqlivestream.mp3

Comment: How or where did you get this link?

Comment: From the page's source code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solved my problem. Yes looking at the Developer Console was the first thing I did too,but I still can't find it. Under 'network? Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var url = "http://mp3.ffh.de/radioffh/hqlivestream.mp3";

var fileWriter = fs.createWriteStream('my.mp3');

request = require('request');
request
.get(url)
.on('error', function(err) {
  // handle error
})
.pipe(fileWriter);

setTimeout(()=>{
    fileWriter.end();

},5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue related to `icecast` module and it because you are using a deprecated module , 
they have another module doing the same functions [icy](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-icy)